# Please explain hasManyThrough relation

Tags: php, laravel

Is there any way to get all relational data with `hasmanyThrough` of third model that has many records with the relation with second model?

As example Main model : Exam id batch_id

relation- belongTo-Batch

second model : Batch id batch_name relation-hasMany-Exam and hasMany-Student

third mode :Student id name batch_id relation- belongTo-Batch

So using Exam model when I try to get batch that belong to it then I can retrieve it but How can I get all student through Exam model related to that batch? I have tried with `hasManyThrough` relation but not working...

Comment: try to check belongsToMany. I mean, just try. :D

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use this in Exam:

```
public function students() {
  return $this->hasManyThrough('Student', 'Batch');
}
```

This won't work, as hasManyThrough assumes that both Student and Batch belong to Exam (Exam belongs to batch)

The easiest way would be something like this: `Exam::find(1)->batch->students`